# How to sort in python based on two parameters but with different orders

Tags: python

I read https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting

`>>> sorted(student_tuples, key=itemgetter(1, 0))
[('andrew', 14, 15), ('jane', 12, 10), (zach, 14, 12)]`

I can sort in two ways but I want to sort in reverse order with the first parameter but not on the second so I get something like

`[('andrew', 14, 15), ('zach', 14, 12), ('jane', 12, 10)]`

How can I do that with the reverse=True parameter?

Currently if I use
`>>> sorted(student_tuples, key=itemgetter(1, 0), reverse=True)`
both of the sorting orders will be from the highest to lowest. I want only one to be from highest to lowest.

Comment: Your example is not clear. Can you please explain with a better example?

Comment: I updated it, is it still not clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this you are looking for:

```
>>> sorted(st, key=lambda x: (x[1]*-1,x[0]))
[('andrew', 14, 15), ('zach', 14, 12), ('jane', 12, 10)]
>>>
```

Comment: I am looking for the combo of them both. SOrting by value of the second item first in descending order, then by the alphabetical order of the first.